# Get frame rate of current Android TV video stream

Tags: android, android-tv

Is there any way to extract the FPS of the currently playing clip, can be YouTube video, or from any streaming content? I will not have the URL or the path of the stream since I need this data in my own service

Comment: Currently playing _where_?  In your app?  In a WebView?  In the browser?

Comment: I'm trying to get this value from within my service and this is ATV, R/S. The actual video could be playing on YouTube, file based, Play Movies or in any other app

Comment: What does "ATV, R/S" mean?  Android TV, SDK versions R and S?

Comment: Yes, sorry, Android TV, version R or S